# Error C2664 Boost Connect

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having a problem with boost connect signal and I'm not sure what has went wrong.

I encountered the following error:

> error C2664: 'void (makVrv::DtDe* )' : cannot convert parameter 1 from makVrv::DtDe** to makVrv::DtDe*

Please help me. Thanks.

```
void ToolBarExerciseControl::TransferMakDe(makVrv::DtDe* de)
{
   deConst = de;
}

void ToolBarExerciseControl::startExercise()
{
   deConst->signal_postInitialize.connect(boost::bind(&loadAccessory, &deConst));
}

void loadAccessory(makVrv::DtDe* de)
{
   de->signal_postInitialize.disconnect(boost::bind(&loadAccessory, &de));
}
```

Comment: `de->signal_postInitialize.disconnect(boost::bind(&loadAccessory, &de));` I'm pretty sure the last ampersand, the one in front of `de`, is not supposed to be there. Probably the same with `deConst`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks. I removed the ampersand and it's working right now for both statements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Do you have any idea if loadAccessory() is ever called? I tried to perform some actions within loadAccessory(). However, they are never called.

Comment: No idea. I know nothing about the library you are using. I just made an educated guess based on the error message alone.